# Records are not showing PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, html, phpmyadmin, xampp

I have a table that has php code in it to output a set of records from a database. The problem is, the records aren't showing. I have similar codes in other tables and they show up right. I tried this in phpMyAdmin and the records show. Am I doing anything wrong? Any help would be much appreciated.

```
<table border style="solid">
<tr><th colspan="2">Finished Tasks</th></tr>
<tr>
        <th>Owner</th>
    <th>Task</th>
</tr>
<!--populate here
<tr><td>Sample Owner</td><td>Sample Finished task</td></tr>
-->
<?php
    //output to Finished Task Table
    #region Finished
    $queryFinished = "SELECT CONCAT(user.User_FName,' ',user.User_LName) as User_Name, task.Task_Name, task.Task_Desc, user_task.Task_DateTaken from user, task, user_task WHERE user.User_Email = user_task.User_Email AND task.Task_No = user_task.Task_No AND user_task.Task_DateFinished LIKE '%thisDate%' AND user_task.Task_IsIssue='0'";
    $resultQueryFinished = mysql_query($queryFinished);
    for($i=0; $i<mysql_numrows($resultQueryFinished); $i++)
    {
        $userName = mysql_result($resultQueryFinished, $i, "User_Name");
        $taskName = mysql_result($resultQueryFinished, $i, "Task_Name");
        $taskDateTaken = mysql_result($resultQueryFinished, $i, "Task_DateTaken");
        $taskDesc = mysql_result($resultQueryFinished, $i, "Task_Desc");
?>
        <tr>
        <td><?php echo $userName; ?></td>
        <td>
        <button class="clickThis">Task Name: <?php echo wordwrap($taskName, 15, "<br />\n"); ?></button>
        <p class="content2">
        Task Description: <?php echo wordwrap($taskDesc, 15, "<br />\n"); ?>     <br />
        Date Taken: <?php echo $taskDateTaken; ?>
        </p>
        </td>
        </tr>
<?php
    }
?>
</table>
```

Comment: `AND user_task.Task_DateFinished LIKE '%thisDate%` - Is `thisDate` really correct...?

Comment: Are you sure that query is returning any results? Output the value of  mysql_numrows to make sure.

Comment: Yeah I tried that. And I've used %thisDate% in other tables which work fine.

Comment: What does the `Task_DateFinished` field contain?

Comment: Got it. Silly mistake. I forgot the $ of thisDate. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check to make sure that you are connecting to the database or to any header include file that you may have.
this is a wild card but its simple debugging. you have $userName = mysql_result($resultQueryFinished, $i, "User_Name");
replace this with $userName = 'ok'; run the code again if you see ok then your result may be empty. if not change the $i=0 to $=1

Comment: I did. The include file is in the header section of the page and I don't use mysql_close until the very end of the page otherwise I'll get an error.

Comment: @VictorSwords you can leave mysql_close out alltogether, this will happen automatically at the end of a script anyway.